# Pandas Compare - How to compare 2 date columns in 2 separate dataframes

Tags: pandas, csv, date, compare

I have once csv with missing dates, I have created a new df of that same date range, without the missing dates. I want to compare the two csvs and place an NaN wherever there are blank dates in the original csv:

Example:

```
    DateTime            Measurement Dates
0   2016-10-09 00:00:00 1021.9      2016-10-09
1   2016-10-11 00:00:00 1019.9      2016-10-10
2   2016-10-12 00:00:00 1015.8      2016-10-11
3   2016-10-13 00:00:00 1013.2      2016-10-12
4   2016-10-14 00:00:00 1005.9      2016-10-13
```

so I want the new table to be:

```
    DateTime            Measurement Dates
0   2016-10-09 00:00:00 1021.9      2016-10-09
1   Nan        00:00:00 Nan         2016-10-10
2   2016-10-11 00:00:00 1015.8      2016-10-11
3   2016-10-12 00:00:00 1013.2      2016-10-12
4   2016-10-13 00:00:00 1005.9      2016-10-13
```

And then I will remove the DateTime column so the final df is a complete list of dates with the missing measurements.

The code I have used thus far:

```
new_dates = pandas.date_range(start = '2016-10-09 00:00:00', end = '2017-10-09 00:00:00')

merged = pandas.merge(measurements, updated_dates,left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense, in your explanation you say you have a csv with missing dates, but your example dataframe has no missing dates, only the output.

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear. I've merged the two data frames and as you can see in the first column (DateTime) the date 2016-10-10 is missing but it is present in the third column (Dates). I want to be able to compare those two columns and identify that 2016-10-10 or any other dates are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your correctly you want to resample your `DateTime` column to a daily frequency and fill the gaps with `NaN`:

```
# Use this line if your DateTime column is not datetime type yet
# df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

dates = pd.date_range(df['DateTime'].min(), df['DateTime'].max(), freq='D')
df = df.set_index('DateTime').reindex(dates).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
       index  Measurement
0 2016-10-09       1021.9
1 2016-10-10          NaN
2 2016-10-11       1019.9
3 2016-10-12       1015.8
4 2016-10-13       1013.2
5 2016-10-14       1005.9
```

---

If you have unique dates, you can use `resample` as well. If your dates are not unique it would aggregate them and take the `mean` of two dates:

```
df.set_index('DateTime').resample('D').mean()
```

**Output**

```
    DateTime  Measurement
0 2016-10-09       1021.9
1 2016-10-10          NaN
2 2016-10-11       1019.9
3 2016-10-12       1015.8
4 2016-10-13       1013.2
5 2016-10-14       1005.9
```

Comment: cool thanks, I just tried running the first request you provided above and got the following error: "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: That means your `DateTime` column has duplicates, so there are multiple measurements for the same date.

Comment: The second solution will work, but be aware that it aggregates the measurements with the same date, and takes the mean of these. @JNix

Comment: Good, don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped so others can be helped as well :) @JNix